# Block Site in Web Browser

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How to block all website in webbrowser control except facebook.com?? 
example:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
   if (webBrowser1.Url.ToString() == "All site from facebook.com")
   {
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Site Blocked");
      webBrowser.Navigated("Http://google.com");
   }
}
```

Comment: Also consider making your `if` statement a != so you do not have to have an empty `if` block, it will be easier to read

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Handle `Navigating` as you're already doing, but cancel it if the URL isn't from Facebook:

```
e.Cancel = !e.Url.Host.EndsWith(".facebook.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two properties in the `WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs` class that can help you. One of them is `Url` and the other is `Cancel`.

Note that `Url` is of `Uri` type, so you can look for "**facebook.com**" easily. If you find "**facebook.com**" then you set the `Cancel` to **true**.

For more information take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowsernavigatingeventargs.url.aspx